# Why declaring these variables in different places within my nested for loop gives me different output images, speaking of blurriness?

Tags: c, filter, cs50

I put `int total_red = 0, total_green = 0, total_blue = 0;`  and `float counter = 0.00;` in the first for loop, it gives me this extremely blurry image after I run the program to convert the original image to a blurring one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsANY.png)

And I also placed these two statements within the second and third for loop. The latter gives me a slightly clear image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQTsM.png) This is the output image after I placed the two statements in the second for loop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTQ85.png) This one results from the changes I made in the third loop

I'm  confused how the location of these two statements produces different output. These variables had all been declared before being used. Why is there that difference?

Below is my code

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE image_copy[height][width];
   
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {   
        
        //process one pixel in a row at the time
        for ( int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            
            int total_red = 0, total_green = 0, total_blue = 0;
            float counter = 0.00;
            //find the neigbhouring pixels in 3x3 box
            //obtain [i][j], [i][j-1], [i][j+1], [i-1][j-1], [i-1][j], [i-1][j+1], [i+1][j-1],[i+1][j], [i+1][j+1]
            for ( int x = -1; x < 2; x++)
            {
            
                //calculate the three channel values of each neigbhouring pixel
                for ( int y = -1; y < 2; y++)
                {
                    int X = x;
                    int Y = y;
                    
                    //filter out the unvalid pixels before carrying on to the following calculation
                    if((i+X) < 0 || (j+Y) < 0 || (i+X) > (height-1) || (j+Y) > (width-1))
                    {
                        //skip this iteration of the inner for loop, statements below will not be executed.
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    total_red = image[i+X][j+Y].rgbtRed + total_red;
                    total_green = image[i+X][j+Y].rgbtGreen + total_green;
                    total_blue = image[i+X][j+Y].rgbtBlue + total_blue;
                    counter++;
                }
                
                
                
            }
            
            image_copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(total_red / counter);
            image_copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(total_green / counter);
            image_copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(total_blue / counter);
            
        }
    }
    
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = image_copy[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image_copy[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = image_copy[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            
        }
    }
    
       

    
    return;
}
```

Comment: "*I also placed*". Are you saying you are *repeating* `int total_red = 0;` at different places? If so, that means you are declaring multiple versions of the variable. The `total_red` in the outer loop will be a different variable to the `total_red` in the inner loops. If you are insre

Comment: @kaylum I'm not redeclaring those variables at different places. I was just playing around these two statements in my code by placing them at different locations each time I compile the code. These two statements were first placed after `RGBTRIPLE image_copy[height][width];` , which gives me a plain brown image. Then I put them within the second loop, and this time, it produces a blur image, but then out of curiosity, I placed them within the first and third for loop, each at a time, giving me different output images. I want to know why that happens.

Comment: You have `float counter` but it should be `int counter`. You have (e.g.) `round(total_red / counter)` but it could be: `round((double) total_red / counter)`

Comment: You need to keep `counter` with `total_*`  otherwise your "average"  division code is not useful.

Comment: @ Craig Estey  If I declare it in int, the round function will give me the wrong value. `total_red` stores an int, and if `counter` was an int as well, the division of the two integers might not produce a correct value, becasue the fractional part of it will be cut off, then the round function will give me an incorrect value.

Comment: @Gem Taylor Not sure what you mean by keeping `counter` with `total_*`, could you expand that a little bit more?

Comment: When you do the `(double)` cast, it works with an `int` counter. This isn't the first `cs50` blur post here on SO and virtually all others do it the way I've described. You can even do the rounding with integer math and it's faster and just as accurate.

Comment: It matters because you're resetting the values of the variables in different places. I'm not even sure the assignments will occur on multiple passes through the same loop? Why not explicitly reset the values when moving to the next pixel?

Comment: @ Craig Estey I'm not very familiar with double. Could you elaborate your thoughts on it? My concern is that the value I get from the division would not be accute, becasue everything after the decimal point will be thrown away. So when you say do the double cast kind of confused me. I'm just been leanring programming for a couple of month, don't know very much. So if you don't mind, could you explain why the double cast is useful in this case?

Comment: @ Drew yeah, you are right. I always have this tendency to declare every variable outside of all the loops, extending the scope of these variable as big as possible.

Comment: So you are trying to get an average pixel value. The average is sum / count, but, critically, that sum must be the sum of the values that you count. The place where you reset the sum MUST be the same place as you reset the count, or you will be summing 900 things but counting 9 things. If you do that with "byte" colour values, you end up with values > 256 after the division, which, when mapped back to a pixel colour will be rubbish.

Comment: @  Gem Taylor Now I get it. Thank you very much!